# How to configure the value for pg_stat_activity.application_name from within a Node.JS application

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I wish to know if there is any way of supplying a value for `pg_stat_activity.application_name` from a Node.js application.

Example: nodejs myapp.js     will show: NodeJs - My App

[image: pgadmin dashboard image link]

Comment: The value for that column is supplied by the application when connecting to the database. E.g. the application can run `set application_name = 'NodeJs - My App'` manually after it established the connection. The JDBC driver supports adding a property to the connection URL - I don't know how this is done in Node.js. But there is nothing you can do "from the outside" - the application needs to be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as **a_horse_with_no_name** suggested, putting **application_name** when you are creating your connection works like a charm in this way:

```
const client = new Client({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'dbname',
  password: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
  application_name: 'a name',    <---- THIS ONE MAKES THE MAGIC :)
});
```

So many thanks!